# The way to use redis hmget on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I have a redis hash containing multiple values, ie

```
myhash f1 "foo" f2 "bar" f3 "mish" f4 "mash"
```

I'd like to extract the values using hmget but stuck on the ruby terminology. I want to do something like:

```
hmget myhash f1 f2 f3 f4
```

but how do I capture the result in ruby variables? THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the result is in the form of a ruby array, so can go:

```
a = hmget myhash f1 f2 f3 f4
```

and then get to each piece of data using

```
a[0]
a[1]
```

etc